# How do I set File Properties for a Compiled IronPython application?

Tags: .net, compilation, ironpython

I am developing a program in IronPython which will be compiled into an exe for later distribution. I have compiled a simple example which demonstrates what I want, which is good - but if I right-click on the generated EXE or DLL, the file-properties (such as File version, Product name, Product version and so on) are empty (or in the case of 'File Version', set to useless values - e.g. '0.0.0.0').

My question is: How can I configure the file properties of a compiled IronPython program?

Thanks,

Comment: This seems to be currently unsupported. I'll have a closer look and possibly create a workaround/fix.

Comment: Ok - thank you. As it happens I have now switched my development over to C# because of some other reasons; however IronPython looks like it's could be very useful for me in the future...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wouldn't mind you giving my pyc version a try in order to verify that it does what you were looking for and possibly marking my answer.

Comment: I can do that, however I can't really say when I'll next be using IronPython - it depends on what projects I get assigned on. I can get back to you if/when I'm back using it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of *pyc.py* does not support setting the meta-information you are asking about.

.NET provides [AssemblyName.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) as well as [AssemblyBuilder.DefineVersionInfoResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzk89196.aspx) for setting the information while assembly building. I created a [pyc version](https://github.com/sopelt/IronLanguages/blob/8bf66102f0f358af8e8ae63e25ee884759bf9684/Languages/IronPython/Public/Tools/Scripts/pyc.py) (as well as a [pull request](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/pull/128)) supporting additional command line arguments for setting the additional meta information.